# How to configure PDF Service Manager so it verifies and I can use cfhtmltopdf?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2021

We're attempting to use  in our development environment, running CF 2021 Enterprise on Windows, but running into some road blocks.

When I attempt to use the `<cfhtmltopdf>` tag on a page, the error message says "No Service Manager is available." I found the PDF Manager in the CFAdmin. There is only one Service Manager listed. I clicked "Verify all Service Managers", which gives "Connection verification failed for PDF Service Manager: localhost. Check logs for more details."

The coldfusion-out log shows "Jul 27, 2023 14:47:32 PM Error [http-nio-8500-exec-8] - Connect to 127.0.0.1:8993 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect [http://127.0.0.1:8993/PDFgServlet/verify"](http://127.0.0.1:8993/PDFgServlet/verify%22)

Web searching led me to the Coldfusion Add-On Service, so we downloaded and installed the Coldfusion Add-On service and restarted ColdFusion. I get the same errors from before.

I have attempted to systematically change the port numbers, as well as toggle the "https enabled" in the Service Manager record for each port number (I tried each port with and without https enabled), but I'm having no luck there, either - same errors as before. Granted, I only tried a handful of ports (8993 down to 8998), but I'm not sure how far I may need to go there.

I'm looking for suggestions for how to configure this so that I can use the `<cfhtmltopdf>` tag.

Comment: I'm sure you've read this documentation, but leaving this here for future reference. You should contact Adobe directly to get some help configuring this service. Depending on how you purchased the license, you should have a contact there for support. https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/pdf-generation-in-coldfusion.html

Comment: @AdrianJ.Moreno, thanks. Yes, I have read the documentation and we've even pulled in Charlie Arehart and left him stumped so far. So, yes, we may have to go directly to Adobe.

Comment: I was told that `cfsup@adobe.com` would be a good contact for help.

Comment: Is the Add-on service running?  Also, what credentials the Add-On service is using?  Do the credentials have the folder permissions?

Comment: @MonteChan, Add-on Services *is* running, logged in as Local System (Charlie did see this and I don't believe had any concerns with it). I'll admit I'm not super familiar with these credentials, but the add-on folder security properties seems to be identical to the ColdFusion 2021 security. Please let me know if I'm looking in the wrong place here.

Comment: @mykaf Just a wild guess, did you check the firewall settings?

Comment: I wouldn't even know where to begin with our firewall.

Comment: I don't think it's quite accurate to say your challenge left me "stumped". I proposed we could enable fr in the add on service to better seen what error was happening (since cf and the add on service logs were not showing us more--and our other diagnostic attempts were not solving things).

Comment: @mykaf regarding to the firewall, you can try by turning it off completely and see if you are still getting the same error.

Comment: @mykaf I have CF 2021 running on my local (Win 11).  cfhtmltopdf works for me.  In my case, when I open up http://127.0.0.1:8993/PDFgServlet/ in the browser, I would get a 400 bad request, which is expected.  At the bottom, there is a link saying Powered by Jetty.  If you were to open http://127.0.0.1:8993/PDFgServlet/ in your browser, what do you see?

Comment: @MonteChan, I get the same error: HTTP ERROR 400 Bad Request
URI: /PDFgServlet/
STATUS: 400
MESSAGE: Bad Request
SERVLET: PDFgServlet

Comment: This doesn't really feel like much of an actual answer, but we ended up reinstalling ColdFusion and then having to modify our java.security file - I think we commented out one of the encryption algorithm options. While working with Adobe, we suspected that our CF installation (by our hosting service) wasn't typical and was preventing the PDF Service from running.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add here that for some readers, the problem described above is simply a result of a problem where the CF addon service (for Solr and/or CFHTMLtoPDF--aka pdfg) has been restarted, while CF was running.

As such, a simple solution (that some have found) has simply been to restart CF.

For those who can't do that, another "trick" is to edit the PDF service definition in the CF Admin (but not change it in any way), where submitting that "change" (in the CF Admin) will "reset" the connection. I have [an extended comment with more detail](https://community.adobe.com/t5/coldfusion-discussions/cfhtmltopdf-fails-after-restarting-services/m-p/13670561#M194672) in an Adobe forum discussion on this matter here.

And for those who may prefer to automate this task (and not "fiddle with" the CF Admin to solve this), I discuss a way to run an Admin API call in the next comment of that thread. Here is the code, to save you going there (and in case that link ever fails):

```
<cfscript>
// Login is always required. 
adminObj = createObject("component","cfide.adminapi.administrator");
adminObj.login("yourCFadminpw");
docObj = createObject("component","cfide.adminapi.document");
// change the args as needed to match your CF Admin settings
docObj.editServiceManager ( "localhost", "127.0.0.1", 8993, 2, "no" );
</cfscript>

PDF manager reset
```